# When Python calls C language, the return value is abnormal

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

When Python calls C language, the return value is abnormal（python3.6.5 call gcc）

I tried to pass the list to the C.so file and return a value. I tested the C language without any problem, but the returned value always changedwhen I use python call c.so file,and sometime the return values even become a negative value.

```
//part c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

extern c;

float get_mod(float *array){
    int N=sizeof(array);
    int i;
    float mod=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;++i){
        mod=mod+pow(array[i],2);
    }
    mod=sqrt(mod);
    return mod;
}

float get_inner(float *array1,float * array2){
    int N;
    N=sizeof(array1);
    int i;
    float inner=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        inner = inner+array1[i]*array2[i];
    }
    return inner;
}

int cos_sim(float *a,float *b){
    float get_mod(float *);
    float get_inner(float *,float *);

    float mod1;
    float mod2;
    float inner;
    float cs;

    mod1=get_mod(a);
    mod2=get_mod(b);
    inner=get_inner(a,b);
    cs=inner/(mod1*mod2);
    float result;
    result=cs*pow(10,3);

    int res=result;
    printf("%d\n",res);
    return res;
}

//part python
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import win32api

dll = ctypes.CDLL(r"E:\whywork\zldf\cosine_similarity_c.so")
cossim=dll.cos_sim
cossim.argtypes=[POINTER(c_float),POINTER(c_float)]
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3],dtype="float64")
arr2 = np.array([1,2,5],dtype="float64")
cossim.restype=c_int
result = cossim(arr1.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)),arr2.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float)))
win32api.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
print(result)
```

I want to know how to set the return value when Python calls C

Comment: FYI: A `numpy.float64` corresponds to the C type `double`, not C `float`.  If you are going to leave the C types as `float`, then use numpy arrays of type `numpy.float32`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried three times according to the method you proposed, but my output are "788439888", "801022704", "146889776".I don't know what's those. The output type of result is int in python. I would like to calculate the cosine similarity of two vectors, but I don't know how to set the return value to get the final similarity. 。

Comment: I don't think your C code is working. In functions get_mod() and get_inner() you use sizeof(array) to get the number of elements within the array but this will give you the size of the pointer. Either 4 on 32-bit system or 8 on a 64-bit system. In your example using arrays of 3 elements you are running out of array bounds which leads to unexpected behaviour/results. You need to add parameters to your C functions to pass size of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changing values are the result of your C code. The value of the N you calculate is wrong, `sizeof(arr1)` tells you the byte size of the pointer and not the number of elements in it. In your code you use the bytes in your code and the bytes that are stored after the arrays in the memory. As @Mathias Schmid mentioned in the comments you have to add the N as parameter.

Here is the C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C"{

    float get_mod(float *array, unsigned int N){
        int i;
        float mod=0;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            mod=mod+pow(array[i],2);
        }
        mod=sqrt(mod);
        return mod;
    }

    float get_inner(float *array1,float * array2, unsigned int N){
        int i;
        float inner=0;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            inner = inner+array1[i]*array2[i];
        }
        return inner;
    }

    int cos_sim(float *a,float *b, unsigned int N){

        float mod1;
        float mod2;
        float inner;
        float cs;
        float result;
        int res;

        mod1=get_mod(a, N);
        mod2=get_mod(b, N);
        inner=get_inner(a,b, N);
        cs=inner/(mod1*mod2);

        result=cs*pow(10,3);

        res=result;
        printf("%d\n",res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

In Python I would recommend just using `import ctypes` or `from ctypes import *`. It was a little bit confusing to me at first. I also updated your python code:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import win32api

dll = ctypes.CDLL(r"E:\whywork\zldf\cosine_similarity_c.so")
cossim=dll.cos_sim
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3],dtype="float32")
arr2 = np.array([1,2,5],dtype="float32")

N = ctypes.c_uint(len(arr1))
result = cossim(arr1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)),
                arr2.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)), N)

win32api.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
print(result)
```

When I run this code the result is always the same (`975`)

Comment: Code looks good, just one note to your answer: sizeof(array) and sizeof(array1) of original code returns size of data type for pointers not size of array in bytes.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid You're right. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help,According to your code,I have been able to get the correct return value.My understanding of "sizeof()" is wrong ,learning ,thank you.

Comment: @wythe You're welcome. I think you've mistaken `len()` in Python with `sizeof()` in C. If you're satisfied with my answer you can accept it.